# How to get the attached disk size on FreeBSD

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd

When I attach a disk to FreeBSD I can list any attached disks by doing:

```
[root@freenas] ~# sysctl kern.disks
kern.disks: xbd2 xbd1 ada0
[root@freenas] ~#
```

How can I then find out the size of each attached disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diskinfo -v ada0` if you just want to see disk size.

If you want to use this info in some script, you can parse `sysctl -n kern.geom.confxml` output.

Comment: diskinfo is better, you get points.

Answer (score 1):

Geometry of each disk can be shown by `fdisk ada0` utility.

Disks used for filesystems are shown by `mount` with no args.

Accessible capacity of the filesystem on a disk can be viewed by `df -h <filesystem>`

Comment: fdisk seems to be the answer.