# How to list all mounted disks and their mount path location on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, mount

On FreeBSD I wish to see all mounted disks and all of their mount locations.

For example this shows my disks.

```
[root@freenas] ~# sysctl kern.disks
kern.disks: xbd2 xbd1 ada0
[root@freenas] ~#
```

Now I have the disks but I don't know where they are mounted.

Comment: You have this question already answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/727256/how-to-get-the-attached-disk-size-on-freebsd

Comment: Its a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use the [mount](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) command

> The system    maintains a list of currently mounted file systems.  If no
>        arguments are given to mount, this list is printed.

Then parse the output looking for the disks you are interested in.